# Methods of denaturing BL21 E.coli other than using lysis buffer and sonication

Tags: bacteriology, lab-techniques, ecoli

The goal is to try different denaturing methods for BL21 *E.coli*. However, finding detailed paper on this is challenging as most articles do not seem to include the details of their denaturing procedure. I am currently using lysis buffer and sonication but I would like to try something else. Any detailed suggestions with reason would be of help.

Comment: By "denaturing methods", do you mean lysis methods? "Denature" typically refers to the unfolding of structured macromolecules (protein, DNA) and not whole cells.

Comment: A detergent-containing lysis buffer along with sonication is basically the gold standard for *E. coli* lysis (which I'm assuming you mean instead of "denaturing", which is something different). Why do you need to try something else? What are you studying, or what are you trying to purify?

Comment: Yes you are right I am trying to alter various methods for the disruption, Lysis of E.coli BLC21 currently I am using sonication and a Lysis buffer that contains 20 mM Tris-HCl, 50 mM NaCl plus 10% lysozyme. But we are looking at a better way or alternative ways that may give similar or better results?

Comment: There's Ye Olde french press method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_pressure_cell_press

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=methods+for+e+coli+cell+lysis THere are a large number of such detailed protocols described